# Account Related List Not Showing Up

Tags: profile, page-layout, sobject, relationships, related-list

I am trying to add an account's related list to the Contact page layout.

It will show up for me in Classic and Lightning, but ONLY me, as I am a sys admin.

The other profiles have to go to classic to view this.

I have tried everything pretty much. I've listened to all of the generic basic answers: "ohhh make sure the profile has crud access and is visible on the object", "make sure you added it to the right layout" etc etc.

I've tried putting in a support ticket but they can't help me without logging into my org, which, goes against compliance at my work.

I am out of luck, has anyone else had this issue or know any way around it?

Comment: field level security do you have access to all fields that you are displaying there also make sure right lightning record page is assign to that user

Comment: I just checked, and they do have visibility and readonly access to the 3 fields on the ``Account`` object. And how would I make sure the right record page is assigned?

Comment: Object Manager | Contact | Lightning Record Pages|view Page Assignments

Comment: Have u assigned the correct lighting page and page layout to the profiles?

Comment: They don't have an assigned ``Lightning Record Page``. But, I edit the profile's designated page layout for ``Contact`` all the time and it updates with no issue. Plus they can see all the other related lists, just not ``Account`` for some reason. Could this be a Salesforce issue? I know for a fact the permissions for the object are where they need to be.

Comment: also check the fls on lookup 'accountid' field  on contact object

Comment: still, nothing. I don't know man :/ This might be a salesforce issue because I have no troubles adding other related lists to page layouts, adding fields, etc. And I can't contact support because they will just want login access, but due to compliance that's a no-go.